# Translating LaTeX

Tags: captions

I have almost zero knowledge of LaTeX so would appreciate help with following:

I have just translated an article in LaTeX from Portuguese to English. All OK, but the word *Resumo* above the abstract and the word *Figura* and *Tabela* underneath each figure and table are still in Portuguese when I generate the PDF. Is there some global command that I need to change in the original file to convert these to English? I cannot find the actual words *Resumo*, *Figura* or *Tabela* in the LaTeX file.

Comment: Is there a line `\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}` somewhere at the top of your document, or maybe in a preamble/header file? If yes, change `portuguese` to `english` there. Otherwise, do you use a special document class?

Comment: Tks v much. I changed brazil to english and after a couple of compilations that did the trick...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.